# JavaScript closing tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have noticed most of the time I write HTML with JavaScript the closing tags "/>" makes the rest of the code in the file, is not identified properly, for e.g. comments are not taken as comments

```
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(
      <FilterableProductTable 
        products={products}/>
    )
  });

  // Checking the intitial state
  it('should initialize the filterText state to an empty string', () => {
    expect(wrapper).to.have.state('filterText').to.equal('');
  });
```

But if I make "/>" to ">", the comment works. Can someone help in explaining this and how to sort this issue?

This is a react code. But this also happened for HTML and wp scripts

Comment: Where is your html?

Comment: You cannot write HTML inside JavaScript. I think you are using React and JSX. *"is not identified properly"* What exactly does that mean? Do you mean syntax highlighting is broken? If sot, that's an issue with the editor and syntax highlighter you are using. You'd have to find one that supports JSX.

Comment: Javascript code blocks begin with <script> and end with </script>

Comment: this looks like react code to me where you have to write the html inside the `render()` . in vanilla js the html and JS are seperate.

Comment: @Niladri ...or shallow rendering using `shallow(<MyComponent />)` as above.. :o)

Comment: @Niladri: It's JSX, not HTML. And it doesn't have to be inside `render()` either, it can be written anywhere. `<Foo />` is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement(Foo)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved in the Sublime editor by installing the Babel package:

"cmd + shift + p" > "Package Control: Install Package" > Babel

Now enable the syntax by:
View > Syntax > Babel > Javascript(Babel)

Comment: it's not a 'problem'- it's a poor coding knowledge.